# light bugs on 3D model

Tags: c++, opengl, lighting

I have this picture below that shows the 3D model and the light is not as I expected, I've already tried many ways but I can't figure out how to fix it. my normal vectors are fine

[image: Cube]

the goemetry:

```
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAOArray);
        glBindVertexArray(VAOArray);

        /* GENERATE THE BUFFERS */
        glGenBuffers(1, &bufferArray);

        /* SELECT THAT BUFFER TO WORK WITH */
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferArray);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myMeshes.at(j).realPositions.size() * sizeof(float), (GLfloat*)RealPos, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glGenBuffers(1, &normalArray);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalArray);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myMeshes.at(j).realNormals.size()*sizeof(float), (GLfloat*)RealNor, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(3, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
```

this is my code:

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {

        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    
        glm::mat4 view = glm::mat4(1.0f); 
        glm::mat4 projection = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)width / (float)heigh, 0.1f, 100.0f);

        view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, transZ)); //this is for scroll mouse
        view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f));
        view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f));
                
        glUseProgram(programT);
        int lightColorLoc = glGetUniformLocation(programT, "lightColor");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(lightColorLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)));

        int objectColorLoc = glGetUniformLocation(programT, "objectColor");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(objectColorLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.31f)));

        glm::vec3 lightPos(2.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f);
        int lightPosLoc = glGetUniformLocation(programT, "lightPos");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(lightPosLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(lightPos));

        int projectionLocLight = glGetUniformLocation(programT, "projection");
            glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionLocLight, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
        glm::mat4 modelLight = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        int modelLocLight = glGetUniformLocation(programT, "model");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLocLight, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(modelLight));

        glm::mat4 viewLight = glm::mat4(1.0f); 
        int viewLocLight = glGetUniformLocation(programT, "view");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLocLight, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(viewLight));

        int viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(programT, "view");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));

        int projectionLoc = glGetUniformLocation(programT, "projection");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

        model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(rotX), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(rotY), glm::vec3(.0f, 1.0f, .0f));
        model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(rotZ), glm::vec3(.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
        int modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(programT, "model");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));

                 

        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureArray[0]);
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(programT, "ourTexture"), 0);
            


            glBindVertexArray(VAOArray[0]);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, myMeshes.at(0).Indices.size());
    

        
        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
        glfwSetScrollCallback(window, scroll_callback);
        glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
        
    }
```

vertex shader used for this project:

```
#version 330 core


layout (location = 0) in vec3 RealPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 vertex_color;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 vertex_textcoord;
layout (location = 3) in vec3 RealNor;


out vec3 vs_pos;
out vec3 vs_color;
out vec2 vs_text;
out vec3 normal;
out vec3 FragPos;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    vs_pos = RealPos;
    vs_color = vertex_color;
    vs_text=vertex_textcoord;
    
    FragPos = vec3(model * vec4(vs_pos, 1.0));
    mat3 normalMat = mat3(inverse(transpose(model)));
    normal = RealNor * normalMat;
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(vs_pos, 1.0);
}
```

fragment shader used:

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 vs_text;
in vec3 normal;

in vec3 FragPos;

uniform vec3 lightPos;
out vec4 gl_FragColor;



uniform vec3 objectColor;
uniform vec3 lightColor;


uniform sampler2D ourTexture;



void main()
{
    vec3 norm = normalize(normal);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPos - FragPos);
    float ambientStrength = 0.1;
    vec3 ambient = ambientStrength * lightColor;
    float diff = max(abs(dot(norm, lightDir)), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = diff * lightColor;
    vec3 result = (ambient + diffuse) * objectColor;
    gl_FragColor =  texture(ourTexture, vs_text) * diff;
}
```

can someone help me to fix this or maybe guide me to solve it?

thanks

Comment: The image can be explained if the normal vectors are wrong. The problem is not caused by the shader or the code, but by the mesh. The normal vectors of the mesh are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It applies that matrix * vector == vector * (matrix)^T

You are calculating normals via `normal = RealNor * normalMat;`

This is not equal to `normalMat * RealNor` which results in wrong normals. So kommutate the expression to `normalMat * RealNor` and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: I changed it but now I got no dark side

Comment: Remove the call of `abs` from diffuse coefficient calc.

Comment: then all the sides become dark

Comment: Normals inverted for some reason? May try by multiply normals with - 1.

Comment: that's why I added  ```abs```

Comment: But then your max function becomes irrelevant

Comment: how can I solve it ?

Comment: Check if your normals are wrong directed by multiplying with -1, like

`normal = -1 * (normalMat * RealNor)`

and see if lighting is correct. if it is correct, make sure that your normals are pointing in the correct direction. this should be done during geometry definition client-side.

Comment: yes when I multiplied by -1, I have illuminated sides but not shadow when rotating the model

Comment: Okay. I don't see any light calc issues in the shader right now, beside the things i told you. Maybe show your geometry definition.

Comment: I updated it, but I think it's okay for the geometry. I think something in my while loop?

Comment: @Gamer *'"I think something in my while loop?"*  - No nothing is wrong with your loop. The normal vectors are wrong.

Comment: @Gamer Multiply by -1 and remove `abs`.